# Lexicographic ordering symfony/doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to order questions by their number. The numbers are filled in by the person posting the question. The numbers can have different structures like

```
1 , 1.2 , 1.1.1
```

Now I want to order the question in lexicographic order so it looks like this

```
1.1

1.1.1

1.2

1.3
```

etc.

Is there any way to do this with Doctrine's OrderBy annotation and if not, how should I do it?

Comment: I guess that a simple ORDER BY this field will be enough (your lexicographic order is the same as standard ordering)

Comment: You're right. I just had to change the datatype for the number field in my DB and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: Is that a string/varchar field? In that case the normal order won't work. It will order `1.10` before `1.2`.

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that. Doesn't quite work how I want it to work. It is a string field. So how should I get order to work?

Comment: I got it working. I set the OrderBy on the wrong entity. I have a section entity which has a oneToMany relation with the question entity. So I had to set the OrderBy on the section entity to make it work.